# Registration and login using firebase, add username

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase stores the email and password.

I need to add username to registration.

I also need to authenticate (Login) Users with Username/Password NOT Email/Password.

Registration should have username, email and password...

While Login should be with username and password.

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private Button btnSignUp;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth auth;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button btnLogin, btnReset;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.login_progressBar);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetPassword();
            //startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //authenticate user
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map username to email. For ex, by creating a table of username and email in db. Then, when user enters username to login, fetch corresponding email and use it to perform simple email - password login.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Username authentication instead of email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120939/username-authentication-instead-of-email)

Alternative is to create a server with a Database instead of Firebase.