# login in angular and firebase with username NO email

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hello Im  doing an app in angular, firebase and ionic. I have used a login starter in my app and I want my app to register with a username, email and password. I need the username for later in the app to put Hello [username]. I have the option to register firebase with the property .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)this property only allows the registration of email and password, how can I add a parameter for username? I would appreciate detailed explanation I am a noob.

I have the code divided into a page and a service and the html part.
-HTML PAGE

```
 <ion-item lines="none">
                    <ion-input class="placeholdertext inputField" type="text" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="name" autofocus="true" padding-start></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item lines="none">
                    <ion-input class="placeholdertext inputField" type="text" placeholder="nombre@dominio.com" [(ngModel)]="email" autofocus="true" padding-start></ion-input>
                </ion-item>


                <ion-item lines="none">
                    <ion-input class="placeholdertext inputField" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" [(ngModel)]="password" padding-start clearInput></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

-REGISTER PAGE TS

register() {
    this.spinner = true;
    this.disabled = true;

    this.auth
      .signupUser(this.email, this.password)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.auth.writeNewUser(this.email, res.user.uid)
          .then(response => {
            this.auth.getUser(res.user.uid).then(user => {
              this.spinner = false;
              this.disabled = false;
              this.route.navigate(['approved']);
              console.log(this.email, this.password );
            });
          })
      })

-FINALLY THE AUTH SERVICE

signupUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)//In this part it does not let me add another parameter
  }

   writeNewUser( email: string, uid: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log(name, uid, email)
    return this.db
      .collection('drivers')
      .doc(uid)
      .set({
        email: email,
        available: false,
        approved: false
      });
  }

  loginUser(  email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword( email, password);
  }


signupUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }
```

As I said before I want both in the registration and login can add another password to enter a username, then when the user login start the app with your username and put hello [username]. Adjoint where this property comes out. createuserwithemailandpassword. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=en-419

I appreciate any help. I also speak Spanish

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120939/username-authentication-instead-of-email

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication doesn't support the use of a username to identify the user.  The user must provide an email address to validate their identity.  If you want to assign a username later, that's fine, but they still wont' be able to sign in with it.  They will always have to use their email address and password.

Comment: And how can I get the name of the users?